# What daily practices (achara - anushtana) should a brahmana follow?

Tags: rituals, brahmins

Brahamanas (at least orthodox followers) are expected to follow a ton of daily achara & anushtana, for e.g.

**Anushtana**:
Get up during brahma muhurta
Do Pratah-Sandhya before sun-rise
Do Ijyai (Aradhana) before eating.

**Achara**:
Wash legs before eating
Attend nature's call with yagnopaveetam on right-ear. Wash legs after nature's call.
Do not touch bed/pillow during day.

etc.

Is there an exhaustive list of NITYA (DAILY) practices brahamanas are supposed to follow, failing which, over an extended period of time, results in loss of brahamana-tvam and they become vratya?

**NOTE**: i'm looking for day-to-day minor details as well, which may not be familiar to most people, i'm not just looking for overall duties like learn & teach vedas.

Comment: Seriously even 'not-bad' and 'non-sectarian' questions like these are downvoted. Why?

Comment: @user1952500 There are serial downvoters with most of authors questions are getting downvoted recently at higher rate!

Answer (score 3):

You are basically asking for EVERYTHING .. so one whole Smriti might be required for answering.

In short, the Brahmins should perform the Shat Karma daily.

> 38. A Brahman, who is given to observe the six duties of his caste, who worships the deities and hospitably receives the guests ; whose
>       meals consist of what remains after(daily) offerings made (on the
>       fire), has never to suffer from misery or want.

The six Karmas are:

> SandyA snAnam japo homo devatAtithi pujanam |
>  Atithyam vaiswadevam
>   cha shat karmAni dine dine ||
>
> 39. Ablution and prayer, inaudible recitation (of sacred words), burnt- offerings, the worship of gods, hospitality to guests
>       unexpectedly come, and offerings made in the name of the Visvadevam, —
>       these are the six duties to be performed every day,

Source - Parashara Smriti's Chapter 1

> Is there an exhaustive list of NITYA (DAILY) practices brahamanas are
>   supposed to follow, failing which, over an extended period of time,
>   results in loss of brahamana-tvam and they become vratya?

There can be many things. In short, a Brahmin becomes a Sudra if he fails to perform the daily bathing for seven days as well as if he fails to do Sandhya for just three days.  Similar is the degradation if he fails to perform Homa for 12 days.

> Without this bath, no acts bear any fruit. Therefore everyday, this
>   morning bath is very necessary. Taking the Kus'a grass in hand, one is
>   to perform one's bath and Sandhyâ. **If for seven days, the morning
>   ablutions are not taken, and if for three days, the Sandhyâs are not
>   performed, if for twelve days, the daily Homas be not performed, the
>   Brâhmanas become S’ûdras.** The time for making the Homa in the morning
>   is very little; therefore lest ablutions be done fully which would
>   take a long time and hence the time for the Homa might elapse, the
>   morning bath should be performed quickly. After the bath the Prânâyâma
>   is to be done. Then the full effects of bath are attained
>
> **Devi Bhagavatam, Book 11, Chapter 3**

Answer (score 3):

As per 'Varnashrama Viplava' by Sri Sitaramdas Omkarnath

> Samo damas tapah saucham kshantir aarjavam eva cha/ Jnanam vijnanam astikyam brahmakarma-swabhabajam

meaning: sama, dama,tapasya,saucha,kshanti,aarjava, jnana and vijnana are brahmin's natural activities.

> The special duties of brahmins are : adhyana(study), yajana(worshiping),daana(donation). Three pro3fessions are allowed : Adhyaapana(Teaching),Yaajana(Worshipping as representative of others) and pratigraha(accepting daana from others).
>
> A brahmin must to Trisandhya Vandana regularly.Otherwise he will be fallen.

Reference: Omkarnath Rachanavali, Mahamilan Math.Vol 6, page 136

He also quotes from Devi-Bhagavatam 12/3

> kuryad anyanna va kutyad anusthaanadikam tathaa/Gayatrimatranistham tu kritakrityo bhabed dwijah.
> yad aksharaika-samsiddheh spardhate brahmanottamah/Hari-Sankara-Kanjottha-Surya-Chandra-Hutaashanair//
>
> **meaning : Even if a brahmin(Dvija) performs any other activity or not, he can get siddhi only by Gayatri. If he becomes siddha even in an akshara of Gayatri, He becomes equal to Chandra, Surya and Agni.** (Ibid, page 275)

Manusamhita (2/87) also says

> japenaiva tu samsiddhyed brahmano naatra samshayah/kuryaad annan na va kurtad maitro brahmano uchchyate

meaning : **A brahmin can attain illumination by the [Gayatri] japa only, hether he does any any duty sacred duty or not.But who is friendly to everybody is a real brahmin.**

Maahabharata (Maha-mokshaparva,chapter 297  says

> naitadrisham brahmanasyaasti vittam yatha ekataa smataa styataa cha/ silam shitir dandanidhanam arjjavam tataschoparamah kriyabhah//

meaning: equality,Truthfulness, Viruous conduct, ahimsa, simplicity and abstaining from kriyas are the wealth of a brahmin.